# Unexpected token error JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently trying to display data which I have loaded via a php file, I've tested the .php file and it works and displays correctly. I am now trying to parse the output to my game with the use of JSON.

This the my code at the moment,

```
myGame.leadScreen = function(game) {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.scoresObject;
    this.scoreText;
};

myGame.leadScreen.prototype = {

    create: function () {
        console.log("in Leaderboard screen");

        var scoreStyle = { font: "bold 20pt Arial", fill: "#ffffff", align: "center", stroke: "#444444", strokeThickness: 5 };
        this.scoreText = this.add.text(this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY, "High Scores", scoreStyle);
        this.scoreText.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);



        this.xhr.open("POST", "leaderboard.php", true);
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        this.xhr.send();

        var self = this;
        this.xhr.onload = function() {

            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                self.scoresObject = JSON.parse(this.resoponseText);
                self.scoreText.text = self.scoresObject[0].name + " " +self.scoresObject[0].score;
            }


        }


        }

};
```

The error comes from the JSON.parse line, Any pointers appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The error is likely coming from your server, specifically the response it is generating. Look at that response to find the error, or add it to your question.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? This might help to help you ;)